# Laravel 5.2 - Simple Select Query returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm running a simple query, but for some reason it's not giving me the correct output.

The user is supposed to give multiple answers to a question through checkboxes. With those answer I try to get the ID's of them out of my DB.

**Here's the code I'm using:**

```
foreach($foodtrucktypes as $foodtrucktype)
{
    $type_id = DB::table('foodtruck_types')
        ->select('id')
        ->where('type', '= ', $foodtrucktype)
        ->get();
    echo $foodtrucktype."<br />";
    var_dump($type_id);
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
}

foreach($locations as $location)
{
    $location_id = DB::table('locations')
        ->select('id')
        ->where('name', '=', $location)
        ->get();

    echo $location."<br />";
    var_dump($location_id);
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
}

foreach($partytypes as $partytype)
{
    $party_id = DB::table('party_types')
        ->select('id')
        ->where('party_type' ,'=', $partytype)
        ->get();

    echo $partytype."<br :>";
    var_dump($party_id);
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

**and this is the response I get:**

> Comfort Food array(0) { }
>
> Desserten array(0) { }
>
> Fastfood array(0) { }
>
> Henegouwen array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#195 (1) { ["id"]=> int(2)
>   } }
>
> Limburg array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#196 (1) { ["id"]=> int(3) }
>   }
>
> Bedrijfsfeest array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#194 (1) { ["id"]=>
>   int(1) } }
>
> Communiefeest array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#197 (1) { ["id"]=>
>   int(2) } }

So the code works, except for the first foreach (foodtruck types), it returns empty arrays and I can't see why.

**[Here's a pic of the DB](https://gyazo.com/673bbf1a6cd47260a864d968b49d8531)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would really suggest using Eloquent models... it makes writing code so much better.

```
$type_id = DB::table('foodtruck_types')
    ->select('id')
    ->where('type', $foodtrucktype)
    ->get();
```

Pherhaps the extra space in the `'= '` was making a difference. You don't actually need to specify it in your just wanting to do an `=` comparison on a Laravel `->where()`. If this doesn't work, try `var_dump()` the `$foodtrucktype` variable?